# Extendscript batch save PDFs

Tags: javascript, directory, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I need a little help here. I want a script that converts all the AI files in all the subfolders into PDFs and puts them in a single folder at the root and I want it to skip any folders named "Resources". I found a script that mostly does what I need it to do and I have modified it further to suit our exact needs. I'm struggling with 2 parts of it though. Specifically lines 33 and 80 are my issues now.

```
#target illustrator

main();

//
function main() {

          var topLevel = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select the top level folder to start converting AI files to PDFX files' );

          var proofFolder = new Folder( topLevel + '/Proofs2/');
                    proofFolder.create();


          if ( topLevel != null ) {

                    processDocs( recursiveFolders( topLevel, /\.ai$/i ), getPDFOptions() );

          };

};

//
function processDocs( aiFiles, opts ) {

          var i, baseName, doc, saveFile;

          for ( i = 0; i < aiFiles.length; i++ ) {

                    doc = app.open( aiFiles[i] );

                    baseName = decodeURI( doc.name.match( /(.*)\.[^\.]+$/ )[1] );
```

//This is line 33//      saveFile = File( proofFolder.path + baseName +  '.pdf' );

```
                    doc.saveAs( saveFile, opts );

                    doc.close( SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES );

          };

};

//
function getPDFOptions() {

    var pdfSaveOpts = new PDFSaveOptions();

    pdfSaveOpts.acrobatLayers = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.colorBars = false;
    pdfSaveOpts.colorCompression = CompressionQuality.AUTOMATICJPEGHIGH;
    pdfSaveOpts.compressArt = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.embedICCProfile = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.enablePlainText = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.generateThumbnails = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.optimization = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.pageInformation = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.preserveEditability = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.pDFXStandard = PDFXStandard.PDFX1A2001;
    pdfSaveOpts.viewAfterSaving = false;


    return pdfSaveOpts;

};

//
function recursiveFolders( fold, exp ) {

          var fileList = Array(); // Our matching files…

          getFiles( fold, exp, fileList );

          return fileList;

};

//
function getFiles( fold, exp, array ) {
```

//This is line 80//      if  (Folder.name !== /\Resources$/){

```
          var i, temp;

          temp = Folder( fold ).getFiles(); // All files and folders…

          for ( i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) {

                    if ( temp[i] instanceof File && RegExp( exp ).test( temp[i].fsName ) ){

                              array.push( temp[i] );

                    };


                    if ( temp[i] instanceof Folder ) {

                              getFiles( temp[i].fsName, exp, array );

                    };

          };

          return array;

        };

};
```

Comment: Errrr... there are no line numbers, making lines 33 & 80 rather hard to find...

Comment: How do I paste the code in with the line numbers?

Comment: If on Linux, do "cat -n yourfile > file2paste" and paste that. Else, comment inside the code where you have problems.

Comment: Okay, I added a comment to those two lines.

Comment: Depending on the value of `proofFolder.path`, you probably need a separator between it and the filename, eg "/" on Mac OSX or "\" in Windows in line 33. Or try hardcoding it to "fred.pdf" for now and see if that works.

Comment: `if (Folder.name !== /\Resources$/)` is (very) improper use of the syntax. To check if the name *ends* with this string, use `if !(Folder.name.match(/\\Resource$/))`

Comment: Thank you Jongware. I am very new to scripting and am just guessing at some things as I go.

Comment: The issue with Line 33 is that I'm trying to use the variable "proofFolder" and when I run it it tells me that the variable is undefined. I defined it in the main function but I don't know how to pass the data to the other function it's used in.

Comment: Did I lose everyone when I said I was new to scripting? ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Line 33:

Variables in Javascript are local to the function they are defined in. That is, if you try

```
a();

function a()
{
    var a1 = 1;
    b();
}

function b()
{
    alert ("var a1 = "+a1);
}
```

you will find `a1` is **undefined** inside function `b`. Two common solutions (there may be more) are to put the variable in the function definition:

```
b(a1);
..
function b (myVarArg)
{
    alert ("var a1 = "+myVarArg);
}
```

or -- simple but slightly error-prone -- declare the variable at the very top of your program before `main`:

```
var a1;
```

This is a quick and simple solution; the variable will be 'visible' inside all functions, and assigning a new value anywhere will work. It is 'slightly error-prone' because a *local* variable with the same name (defined inside a function) will effectively 'hide' the *original*. Thus, if used careless, you could end up with a construction such as this:

```
var a1 = 1;
a();
alert ("var a1 = "+a1);

function a()
{
    var a1 = 2;
    b();
    alert ("var a1 = "+a1);
}

function b()
{
    alert ("var a1 = "+a1);
}
```

Fortunately, your use of clear, descriptive variable names will help you here.

---

#### Line 80

```
if (Folder.name !== /\Resources$/) ...
```

Improper use of proper Javascript syntax ☺

1. `!==` is not a valid comparison operator. Use either `==` (Test if Equal) or `===` (Test if Very Equal -- see [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for some gritty details), and `!=` for Test if Not Equal.
2. You can compare a string to another but not to a GREP expression. The notation `/.../` is reserved for GREP expressions *only*, for strings you need `"..."` or `'...'`. While it's true that *some* functions may accept both GREP and regular strings, this test does not.
3. To use a GREP string in a comparison, use the String function [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

   ```
   if (Folder.name.match(/\\Resources$/)) ...
   ```

   Note the double end parentheses (one for the enclosing `if` and one for the `match` function) and **double** backslashes, because the backslash is a 'special character' inside a GREP string. (It is special inside a *Javascript* string as well, so whatever you intended to use, it possibly could be called Improper Syntax #4.)

---

#### Will this Fix Everything and Make It Work?

<s>Untested.</s> Without these corrections, your script will not work. With them, it should at least do *something* (if your logic is sound, your paths exist, your input is right and your Illustrator constants have the correct name).

<s>Provisionally, I'd hazard to say it should work.</s>

---

#### Addendum

It took some debugging to find out the *real* problem .. Debug strategy: inserting `alert` before suspicious lines, showing values of important variables. Run, wait for results, rinse, repeat.

First off: passing on `array` as a function parameter seems to have been a Not-Good idea. I found that the array got copied over and over onto itself (or perhaps it was just the result of my tinkering). I think the safer way is to have `getFiles` return *only* the newly-added files, and concatenate the result to its *current* version (i.e., "in" the routine from whence you called `getFiles`, where it doesn't matter if it was a previous incarnation of `getFiles` or not). See (I think!) my warning on modifying 'local', 'global', and/or 'passed' variables above.

```
function getMyFiles( fold, exp ) {
//This is line 80//
    if (!fold.name.match (/(\\|\/)Resources$/)) {

          var i, temp;
          var array = [];

          temp = Folder( fold ).getFiles(); // All files and folders…

          for ( i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) {

                    if ( temp[i] instanceof File && RegExp( exp ).test( temp[i].fsName ) ){
                        //  alert ('path '+fold+', adding '+temp[i]);
                              array.push( temp[i] );

                    };


                    if ( temp[i] instanceof Folder ) {

                             array = array.concat (getFiles( temp[i], exp ));

                    };

          };
        //  alert ('array is '+array.length+'\n'+array.join('\n'));

          return array;

        };
        return [];
};
```

You would call this function as before in your original `recursiveFolders` function, but this time don't pass the array but *assign* it:

```
function recursiveFolders( fold, exp )
{
          var fileList = Array(); // Our matching files…
          fileList = getFiles( fold, exp );
    // alert ('Filelist is '+fileList.length+'\n'+fileList.join ('\n'));
          return fileList;

};
```

Only when I got *that* part working, I got the same error you did, per your comment "fold.match is not a function". That took a minute or so of head-scratching. As it turns out, the Javascript parser was right. *Initially*, the `fold` argument is a `Folder` and to get its name, you need `fold.name`. But look in your own code: you used in the *recursive* call to itself the argument `temp[i].fsName`, which is a `String`! Hence, no `name`, hence, error.

First, I bluntly converted `fold` to always-a-String using `fold.toString` (which works on Folder and String alike), but then I changed my mind and used `fold.name` for consistency, and call `getFiles` with the "proper" argument: `temp[i]` instead of `temp[i].fsName`. Now it seems to work -- for real. (Said with slightly more confidence.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give a detailed explanation. Before getting your answer I did make the variable a global variable and it worked. I've seen people say that isn't always the best solution but it did work for this situation and I think my script is simple enough to not cause a problem.

For the folder name match, I've put the correct syntax in and it's still not skipping those folders. Do I have it in the wrong place? This is what I have for that line now:

    `if (!(Folder.name.match(/\\Resources$/))){`

Comment: Ah -- the *syntax* is correct, but the premise "we're now looking at `Folder.name`" is not. The folder name is stored at that point in the function argument `fold`. Try `if (fold.name.match ..`.

Comment: Using (fold.name.match... results in an "undefined" error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to remotely debug this. Try `if (fold.match` (perhaps `fold` is no longer a `Folder` name at that point, but just a simple string).

Comment: Nope. Now it's saying "fold is not a function". Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: It ought not to say so .. Possibly a typo? The full line should read by now `if (!fold.match(/\\Resources$/)) {` (followed by what you already had).

Comment: Still says "fold.match is not a function".

Comment: See the addendum to my original answer.

Comment: Well, for whatever reason I'm getting all kinds of errors thrown at me now when I run it in places that were fine before. I think I'm going to give it a rest for tonight and try again tomorrow.